# Apache (con "wsgi_mod") solo muestra mi código de Python en vez de correrlo

Tags: python-3.x, apache2

Estoy en una clase de python y actualmente estamos trabajando con servidores, con Apache y wsgi_mod. Cuando lo inicio, el apache muestra el código pero nada más, no ejecuta y no muestra errores, sólo muestra el código.

Efectivamente tuve muchos problemas cuando instale el mod, pero ahora no se cual es el problema....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]